# Five-line inscription: Equilateral triangle, one of whose points is given, in circle with unknown center

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

**PROBLEM** Here is a surprisingly intriguing challenge posed on Euclidea, a mobile app for Euclidean constructions. I have a geometric construction that achieves the goal but not within the constraints. Could anyone advise on a construction that would fit within these constraints?

> **Given** A point $P$ on a circle $O$ whose center is *not* given.
>
> **Goal** Inscribe an equilateral triangle $\Delta{PQR}$ in $\bigcirc{O}$.
>
> **Constraints** Construct all three sides of the $\Delta{PQR}$ to achieve the goal. Only an unmarked straightedge and a *non-rusty collapsible* compass (*i.e.*, a compass that, while on paper, can have any radius but which cannot maintain said radius when not on paper) can be used. Use only from the construction steps below a number of steps that together require just *five* lines in total.
>
> 1. Construct a point: 0 lines (L).
> 2. Mark the intersection of two curves with a point: 0L.
> 3. Construct a new line (*or line segment or ray): 1L.
> 4. Extend a *given* line segment (*or ray): 1L.
> 5. Construct a circle (*non-rusty collapsible* compass): 1L.
> 6. Construct the perpendicular bisector of a line segment: 1L.
> 7. Construct a new line perpendicular to an old line: 1L.
> 8. Construct an angle bisector: 1L.
>
> **Hints from Euclidea** A known solution employs five constructions in the order: Circle, circle, perpendicular bisector, perpendicular bisector, and line.

**PREVIOUS WORK** As mentioned above, I have a construction that matches neither the 5L-constraint nor the hint. The following figure accompanies the six-line construction below, where the given and goal are shown as an inset:

[image: 6L construction to this problem]

1. Construct a point $A \ne P$ on circle $\bigcirc{O}$ **[0L running total]**.
2. Construct $\bigcirc{A(P)}$ centered on point $A$ and with radius $AP$ **[1L running total]**.

   - $\bigcirc{A(P)}$ also intersects $\bigcirc{O}$ at another point $B \ne P$.
3. Construct $\bigcirc{P(B)}$ **[2L running total]**.

   - $\bigcirc{P(B)}$ also intersects $\bigcirc{A(P)}$ at another point $C \ne B$.
   - Therefore, $\bigcirc{P(C)} = \bigcirc{P(B)}$.
   - Also, $\overline{CP}$ is tangent to $\bigcirc{O}$ at point $P \Longrightarrow m\angle{CPO} = 90^\circ{}$.
4. Construct $\bigcirc{C(P)}$ **[3L running total]**.

   - $\bigcirc{C(P)} \cap \bigcirc{P(C)} = \lbrace D, E\rbrace$.
   - $\bigcirc{C(P)} \cong \bigcirc{P(C)} \Longrightarrow m\angle{CPD} = m\angle{CPE} = 60^\circ{} \Longrightarrow m\angle{DPE} = 120^\circ{}$.
   - Without actually constructing anything: Let $\overrightarrow{EP} \cap \bigcirc{P(C)} = E' \Longrightarrow$ $m\angle{DPE'} = m\angle{EPE'} - m\angle{DPE} = 180^\circ{} - 120^\circ{} = 60^\circ{}$.
   - Therefore, $\angle{DPE'}$ is the first corner of the desired triangle.
5. Construct $\overline{DP}$ **[4L running total]**.

   - $\overline{DP} \cap \bigcirc{O} \cap \neg P = Q$.
   - $\overline{PQ}$ is the first side of the desired triangle.
6. Construct $\overline{DP}$ **[5L running total]**.

   - $\overline{EP} \cap \bigcirc{O} \cap \neg P = R$.
   - $\overline{PR}$ is the second side of the desired triangle.
7. Construct $\overline{QR}$ **[6L running total]**.

   - $\overline{QR}$ is the last side of the desired triangle. $\blacksquare$

Comment: How do they define "construct an old line"? I am not familiar with the concept.

Comment: I'll clear it in the text: Extending a pre-existing ('old') line in any direction is a 1L move.

Comment: Why would one need that? Why can't "we" always construct a line to be exceptionally long the first time? Do they have a maximum length of a segment that can be constructed? (and if so, how is it related to anything else in the problem)

Comment: @mathguy Any lines that the player constructs are infinite. But in some problems (obviously not this one), finite lines are given in the context of a given geometric figure. Feel free to disregard this point. I myself think it does not apply here. In noting that extending old lines costs 1L, I was simply passing along information about how Euclidea counts construction moves.

Comment: Is a collapsible compass one that cannot hold its radius once removed from the surface?  Or simply a non-rusty compass? (ETA: Ahh, apparently it's the former.)

Comment: @Brian Tung: Thanks for the clarification on rusty vs collapsible compasses. I've clarified my question in response.

Comment: Does constructing the line equidistant to two points (the perpendicular bisector of the segment joining them) count as one line or two?

Comment: @Semiclassical It counts as one, as noted above. I do think that counting the perpendicular bisector as a 1L move is a bit strange since it requires three elementary moves (circle, circle, line). Not coincidentally, Euclidea has an E-metric (in contrast to the L-metric) that does count the perpendicular bisector as a 3E move.

Comment: If the following move is allowed, I have a solution: "Given a point $P$ and a circle $O$, construct the point $P'$ which is antipodal to $P$ on $O$." (Alternatively, construct the circle centered at $P$ which is tangent to $O$.) In that case, one can construct circles centered at $P$ and $P'$ whose radius is the diameter of $O$, and use their points of intersection to construct bisectors forming two of the sides of the triangle.

Comment: @Semiclassical I might be missing something that a step-by-step construction would clarify. My current understanding is that you are using the nomenclature in the figure and that $P'$ is the point on $\bigcirc{O}$ opposite $P$. If that is the case, how would one find $P'$ with enough L-moves left for the other steps? (I already use up my allotted 5 L-moves just to find $P'$.) Would appreciate more color. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194028/compass-and-straightedge-contruction-of-an-equilateral-triangle-inscribed-in-a-g, which has the 6 edge solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Euclidea's hint, I think this works (barring possible pathological placement of $A$ that I haven't checked) ...

[image]

Let the given point be $P$ and the given circle be $p$.

1. *Let* $A\neq P$ be a point inside circle $p$. **[0 lines]**
2. **Construct** circle $a$ about $P$ through $A$. **[1 line]**

   - *Let* circles $p$ and $a$ meet at points $B_1$ and $B_2$.
3. **Construct** circle $b$ about $B_1$ through $P$. **[2 lines]**

   - *Let* circles $a$ and $b$ meet at points $C_1$ and $C_2$.
4. **Construct** line $c_1$ as the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{C_1B_2}$. **[3 lines]**

   - *Let* circle $p$ and line $c_1$ meet at $Q$.
   - *Note* that $P$ lies on $c_1$.
5. **Construct** line $c_2$ as the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{C_2B_2}$. **[4 lines]**

   - *Let* circle $p$ and line $c_2$ meet at $R$.
   - *Note* that $P$ lies on $c_2$.
6. **Construct** $\overleftrightarrow{QR}$. **[5 lines]**

   - *Note* that $\triangle PQR$ is equilateral, as desired.

---

For proof, consider this (differently-tinted) sub-figure:

[image]

From congruent equilateral triangles $\triangle B_1 P C_1$ and $\triangle B_1 P C_2$, we deduce that $\stackrel{\frown}{B_1 C_1} \cong \stackrel{\frown}{B_1C_2}$, and thus also that $\angle B_1 B_2 C_1 \cong \angle B_1 B_2 C_2$ (as inscribed angles subtending congruent arcs) with common measure $30^\circ$. A trivial angle chase through right triangles $\triangle B_2 M_1 D_1$ and $\triangle B_2 M_2 D_2$ (and $\triangle B_2 M_2 N$, if you like) shows, then, that $\triangle PD_1D_2$ is (equiangular, and therefore) equilateral, so that the bisector of $\angle D_1 P D_2$ is perpendicular to the common chord $\overline{B_1B_2}$ of (in the notation of the construction) circles $p$ and $a$.

We have shown that lines $c_1$ and $c_2$ (1) meet at a $60^\circ$ angle at $P$, and (2) have an angle bisector that passes through the center of circle $p$. Consequently, they are necessarily side-lines of an equilateral triangle inscribed in $p$ with vertex $P$. $\square$

Comment: Very nice. Though, I think one can just take $A$ to be a point on the circle $O$ to start with (so that $B_1=A$) rather than pick some arbitrary point inside.

Comment: I am not convinced. $\widehat{QPR}$ is clearly a $60^\circ$ angle with this construction, but why $PQR$ is equilateral?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree: Constructing a 60-degree angle around the given point $P$ has always been easy, but showing that said angle leads to an equilateral triangle has always left me scratching my head.

Comment: @Semiclassical: If $A$ is chosen somewhere on the circle, then it *might* be the antipode of $P$, which is problematic.

Comment: Playing around with Geogebra bears out that the triangle is indeed equilateral, but like @JackD'Aurizio I can't see why it's so. I also noticed in Geogebra that, regardless of the choice of $A$, there seems to be a common intersection between the circle $b$, the line $c_2$, and the segment $\overline{B_2 C_1}$.

Comment: (+1) Oh, ok, it works. The angle between $QP$ and $PB_1$ is the angle formed by two perpendicular bisectors of $B_2 C_1 C_2$, that equals $\widehat{C_2 C_1 B_2}$, that is also the angle between $RP$ and $PB_2$. Sorry for the previous moment of non-belief. But maybe it is better to prove that $PQR$ is actually equilateral in your answer.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: No problem. Actually, you beat me to a proof. I posted my answer solely on the basis of a GeoGebra sketch that showed the constructed $\triangle PQR$ consistently overlaying a proper equilateral. I was hoping an "obvious" proof would spring to mind as I was composing my answer; it didn't happen, but I thought I might as well post the answer while I puzzled over why exactly it worked. Thanks to you, I can stop puzzling. :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, thanks for your proof. I hope to understand it a bit better, though. You mentioned 'the angle formed by two perpendicular bisectors of $B_2C_1C_2$', but that notation is a bit non-standard for me. Could you explain a little more? Thank you so much.

Comment: @PDE: It is worth noticing that a bit of angle chasing along the previous lines also proves the concurrency spotted by Semiclassical. Anyway, the angle between $QP$ and $PB_1$ is the angle between the perpendicular bisector of $C_1 C_2$ and the perpendicular bisector of $C_1 B_2$, hence it equals $\widehat{C_2 C_1 B_2}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat{C_2 P B_2}=\widehat{RPB_2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think I get it now: (1) *Let* $O$ be the center of $\bigcirc{p}$. (2) Both $B1$ and $B2$ are on both $\bigcirc{p}$ and $\bigcirc{a}$, so $\angle{B_1PB_2}$ must be reflectionally symmetrical with respect to $\overline{OP}$. (3) Moreover, according to your previous comment, the angles adjacent to $\angle{B_1PB_2}$, namely $\angle{B_1PQ}$ and $\angle{B_2PR}$, are congruent. (4) Thus, $\angle{QPR}$ is also reflectionally symmetrical w.r.t. $\overline{OP}$. (5) That, along with the fact that $\angle{QPR} = 60^\circ$, proves that $\Delta{QPR}$ is an equilateral triangle, as desired.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the proof. Much clearer and more intuitive angle-chase than the one I provided below. Combining your 9E/5L solution with my original 6E/6L solution meets all of Euclidea's challenges for this question. Just one more question from last night's discussion is left, though: Why is point $N$ (in the proof) always on circle $b$ (in the construction)?

Comment: @PDE: Regarding $N$ ... Simply note that $\square C_1 C_2PN$ is cyclic, because its opposite angles $\angle N$ and $\angle C_2$ are supplementary.

Comment: @Blue: I see. Or with a bit more detail: $\angle{C_1C_2P} = (\angle{B_1C_2P})/2 = 60^\circ = 30^\circ$. Also, $\angle{C_1NP} = 180^\circ - \angle{PNM_1} = 180^\circ - 30^\circ = 150^\circ$. Therefore, $\angle{C_1C_2P}$ and $\angle{C_1NP}$ are supplementary to each other and are opposite angles in $\square{C_1C_2PN}$. Thus, all points of this quadrilateral are on one circle, *i.e.*, this quadrilateral is cyclic. But $C_1$, $C_2$, and $P$ have been constructed to be on on circle $b$. $N$ must also be on circle $b$, then.

Comment: @PDE: You could also ignore mention of the specific quadrilateral. The fact that $\angle PNC_1$ has measure $150^\circ$ indicates (via a converse of the Inscribed Angle Theorem) that $N$ lies on an arc the circle for which chord $\overline{P C_1}$ subtends an angle whose measure (the "long way around") is $2\cdot 150^\circ$. Clearly that center must be $B_1$, so that circle must be $b$. (This is basically why the "cyclic convex quad $\leftrightarrow$ supplementary opposite angles" characterization works.)

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a proof of the construction by @Blue:**

[image]

1. $\angle{B_1C_1P} = 60^\circ$ is bisected by $\overline{C_1C_2} \Longrightarrow \angle{C_2C_1P} = 30^\circ$.
2. *Let* $x := \angle{B_2C_1P} \Longrightarrow \angle{B_2C_1B_2} = \angle{B_1C_1P} + \angle{B_2C_1P} = 30^\circ + x$.
3. $\overline{B_2C_1} \perp \overline{PQ}$ and $\mathbf{(2)} \Longrightarrow \angle{PST} = 60^\circ - x \Longrightarrow \angle{SPT} = 30^\circ + x$.
4. Inscribed Angle Theorem and $\mathbf{(2)} \Longrightarrow \angle{C_2PB_2} = 2\angle{B_2C_1C_2} = 60^\circ + 2x$.
5. $\overline{PR}$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{B_2C_2}$ and $\mathbf{(4)} \Longrightarrow \angle{B_2PR} = 30^\circ + x$.
6. $\overline{PR}$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{B_2C_2}$ and $\mathbf{(4)} \Longrightarrow \angle{C_2PR} = 30^\circ + x$.
7. $\overline{PS} \perp \overline{B_2C_1} \Longrightarrow \angle{C_1SP} = 60^\circ - x$.
8. From $\mathbf{(3)}$, $\angle{B_1PC_2} = \angle{C_2PS} + \angle{SPT} = \angle{C_2PS} + (30^\circ + x) = 60^\circ$ $\Longrightarrow \angle{C_2PS} = 30^\circ - x$.
9. By $\mathbf{(6)}$ and $\mathbf{(8)}$, $\angle{QPS} = 60^\circ$.
10. From $\mathbf{(3)}$ and $\mathbf{(5)}$, $\angle{B_1PO} = \angle{B_2PO} \Longrightarrow \angle{TPS} + \angle{OPQ} = \angle{B_2PR} + \angle{OPR}$  $\Longrightarrow \angle{OPQ} = \angle{OPR}$.
11. SSA congruence, $\mathbf{(10)}$, $OP = OP$, $OQ = OR \Longrightarrow \Delta{OPQ} \cong \Delta{OPR} \Longrightarrow PQ = PR$.
12. From $\mathbf{(9)}$ and $\mathbf{(11)}$, $\Delta{PQR}$ is equilateral. *QED.* $\blacksquare$