# Straightedge and compass construction of an inscribed equilateral triangle when the circle has no center

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Given a circle, but not its center, construct an inscribed equilateral triangle in as few steps as possible.

I have a construction that works, but I am really having trouble understanding **why** the construction works. I will attach a photo of my construction below.

[image]

Comment: Mind adding an explanation of the construction?

Comment: Note that because you draw $ED=BE=BD$, then $\triangle BED$ is equilateral. Then $\angle GDF$ is central, but looking at half the arc as the angle $\angle DEB$, which is of $60$ degrees. Then $\angle GDF$ is also $60$ degrees. So, the arc $HG$ is of $60$ degrees. It remains to center the angle looking at the chord $HG$, which by symmetry is the point $B$.

Comment: @DonThousand I began with circle with no center (so ignore A), and then created circle with center B and a random radius. Then I created circle with center D and radius BD. I then drew lines through ED and EF to create the vertices of the triangle. I found the triangle to be BGH.

Comment: To explain properly why '$B$ is centered over the arc $HG$: The angle $\angle FDB$ is also $60$, since it is the other half of the arc subtended by the angle $\angle DEB$. Therefore, arc $BH$ is of $60$ degrees. This gives that $\angle BGH=60$. That is why $B$ is centered over the arc $HG$.

Comment: This is must shorter than the "canonical" solution of constructing the vertices of an inscribed regular hexagon and connecting every other side.  I like it!

Answer (score 4):

$\triangle BDF$ is an equilateral triangle, so angle $\angle BDF$ has measure $60$. So $m\angle BGH=m\angle BDH=60$, since these two angles are subtended by the same arc $BH$. And $\triangle BED$ is also equilateral, so the remaining angle $\angle HDG$ on the line $EG$ has measure $60$.  But $\angle HBG$ has the same measure as $\angle HDG$, since they are subtended by the same arc $HG$. This establishes that two of the angles in $\triangle BGH$ are $60$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method, which requires identifying a diameter but not the center.

Select any point $A$ on the circle.  Center the compasses there and draw an arc through two point $B,C$ on the circle.

Bisect $\angle BAC$, identifying point $D$ as the angle-interior point where the bisector intersects the circle.  Center the compasses on each endpoint of $AD$ and draw an arc through the other endpoint, the two arcs intersecting at point $E$ (either of two choices).

Draw $AE$, which intersects the circle at point $F$ such that **chord $DF$ measures one side of the triangle**, and copy the chord around the circle accordingly.

Also $AF$ measures one side of an inscribed hexagon, so this polygon is obtainable too.